# Delete all lines that appear only once

Tags: windows, nlp, text-processing

I have a huge text file. Most lines appear two times or more often. Some only do appear once. How do I identify those and get rid of them?

From the following list:

```
arterias arcuadas
arterias arcuadas
arterias arcuatas
arterias arqueadas
arterias arqueadas
```

I want to identify

```
arterias arcuatas
```

Comment: What is the platform you are using to accomplish the task

Comment: Windows - I add the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 0):

I used (via Cygwin on Windows)

```
uniq -c > newfile.txt
```

to save a new file with counted line numbers, i.e. my result looked like this:

```
2 arterias arcuadas
1 arterias arcuatas
2 arterias arqueadas
```

Now I was able using the regex

```
^1 .*$
```

to delete the single lines.